# Problemas al cargar una tabla con $ajax

Tags: php, html5, ajax, bootstrap-4

Estoy intentando pintar en el html el body de una tabla pero tengo el siguiente problema:

1) Me muestra la primera fila "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla" y en seguida las filas renderizadas.

2) Cuando intento filtrar desaparecen los datos.

Estoy trabajando con php mvc
vista:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

archivo js
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla html
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco toda ayuda que puedan

Comment: Bienvenido Miguel a [es.so] te recomiendo sustituir las capturas de pantalla por el codigo directamnte. Mas info en [ask]

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [editar](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Usa el api de la datatable, con ella no tienes que concatenar los rows de la tabla

```js
var DT = $('table#dt_catalogoDetalle').dataTable({"destroy": true, "autoWidth": true, "searching": true, "iDisplayLength": 10}).api();//Inicializas la tabla

$.each(respuesta, function(key,valor){
       DT.row.add([valor.id, valor.nombre, valor.descripcion]);//Agregas los rows
})

DT.clear().draw();//Limpias y creas de nuevo en caso de algun refresh
```

Con este código se crea la datatable automáticamente

Saludos